# Select all column except particular column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using asp.net and msaccess2003 and 30 to 40 column in my table, i want select all column but except particular column and don't need column i know at program execution

Comment: SELECT *[^column] FROM Laptop

Comment: try this code but no use

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET, load a DataTable with one record. Then, you can build a String of columns excluding the column you wish to exclude.

```
Dim tblTemp As DataTable
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable"
'Fill tblTemp from the above sql 

' generate a columns list string excluding the Blah column
Dim L As Integer
Dim columns As String
For L = 0 To tblTemp.Columns.Count - 1
    If tblTemp.Columns(L).ColumnName <> "Blah" Then
        If columns <> "" Then columns &= ", "
        columns &= tblTemp.Columns(L).ColumnName
    End If
Next

Dim FinalSQL As String
FinalSQL = "SELECT " & columns & " FROM MyTable"
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Get the data into a temp table */
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM YourTable

/* Drop the cloumns that are not needed */
ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN ColumnToDrop

  // Get results and drop temp table 
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Hope this helps